# Unable log in to microsoft logine.live

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I am unable to view the properties of a web role in Visual Studio 2013 Professional.  It attempts to login to Microsoft login live and throws a javascript error `evt_Login_onload` is undefined`.  Visual Studio then fails to respond and shuts down.  I am also unable to login to the Azure Portal using IE 10.  Google Chrome works just fine.

On another computer (Windows 7 running in VMWare Fusion 6 on a MacBook Pro) I have no problem.  My primary development computer (Win 7 Ultimate) no longer is able to view or change the properties of a Web Role. I have tried deleting all cookies and history, but this does not solve the problem.

The URL that appears in the script error is:
`https://login.live.com/login.srf?cbcxtazumanage&popupui=1&vv=&username=jimrand%40ix.netcom.com&mkt=&lc=@wfesh=&popupui=1&wa=wsignin 1`

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm experiencing the same issue on Win Server 2012 while trying to get a WinRT Developer License.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem today.

Setup was:

- Windows Vista
- IE 9

Enabling TLS 1.0 resolve the issue.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by enable `Active Scripting` setting in Security tab for Internet zone.
It looks like this is required despite I got `https://*.live.com`  and `*.live.com` added to list of trusted sites. My environment is: Win 2008R2 Std SP1 64b, IE11 - in Remote Desktop
I hope this will help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with Windows Server 2012.
We also tried to enable every available setting in IE, but finally we found out that some TLS handshakes in Windows itself were disabled (in some Crypto module), thus no application was able to communicate with the login scripts.
Try this page, if it fails, you still need to change some settings ;))
https://auth.gfx.ms/16.000.25553.00/R3WinLive1033.css